MimeKit/MailKit Question "Not recognized octetstream element in BodyPart of MimeMessage"
I currently have a issue with a MimeMessage from my email server in a C#/DOTNet Winforms Environment.
For most other messages, this works, but for this one the attachment is not parsed as an attachment in the MimeMessage.
From what I could gather, it is a .pdf-File and a .txt-File. Both are part of the BodyPart list of the MimeMessage, but both are not marked as Attachments or available in the attachment list.
Especially the PDF-File is kinda weird because it seems to be recognized as a octet-stream. Which is weird because other PDFs are properly parsed in the E-Mail Client we have created.
So, my issue is I want to interpret the body parts, but I also don't want to blindly accept all kinds of attachments and creating a security issue. As such, just iterating the body parts and trying to parse all the body parts seems risky.
Is there a easy way to fix this? To get all the attachments even if they are not marked properly as attachments in the MimeMessage?
With highest regards
Fabian Saam
I checked if it is a issue with the version of MimeKit... doesn't seem that way? Not 100%.
I also tried to save the email again, when saved with Thunderbird it seems to work properly.

The PDF and text files appearing or not appearing in the MimeMessage.Attachments list is NOT related to whether they are being "parsed" correctly vs not correctly, it is a matter of whether they have a Content-Disposition header with a value of attachment.

So, my issue is I want to interpret the body parts, but I also don't want to blindly accept all kinds of attachments and creating a security issue. As such, just iterating the body parts and trying to parse all the body parts seems risky.

I don't see how this would be any riskier than trusting everything in the MimeMessage.Attachments list.

What I meant by "it being parsed" was based on my assumption that the e-mail application that sent this e-mail used a format that was not properly parsed (aka marked as attachment).
Also, in terms of more risky: In the body parts are also non-attachment files that could be hidden in the e-mail. If a user would download that file and there is malicious content in there, it would have been only visible in my editor in that case.

Attachments are not any safer than body parts. It's a semantic difference only.
